# Proper Java Project Structure for an Enterprise Application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am newbie to Java. In Visual Studio you have options to create sub-projects under a single project, wherein these sub-projects can be of different types like web, ER etc. This allowed me to create one easy-to-deploy solution with some sub-solutions. Now, I have this application with different modules (requiring different project types) to develop in Java. Modules can be assumed as JPA type, Java Type, Web Type. 
Is there similar way (like Visual Studio) in Eclipse for creating sub-solutions under main solution? If not, how can I construct a proper project structure which is easy to maintain and deploy? Please give comprehensive answer, considering my C# background.

Comment: In the project properties, you can create links to other projects in the workspace: so you can link to the parent, for example.

Comment: Also, consider using maven (Eclipse has a plugin allowing you to use maven from the IDE) to manage such things, like parent-child relations.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking for is probably [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). Almost all Java web projects now use Maven as the build system and it enforces a project structure. A really great example of this is the Java EE demos that come with the JavaEE 7 tutorial. You can download the SDK, tutorials and demos from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html). The best thing about Maven is it's IDE independent so you can (fairly) easily switch from Eclipse to NetBeans to whatever. Additionally, both Eclipse and NetBeans have their own project structure but there's generally not much advantage to using it and it ties you into that IDE.

The other popular build system is [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). Ant doesn't impose a structure on your project but it's arguably more flexible on what you can do with it.

Comment: I went through maven. It allows to create a project and its sub-projects (parent module & child modules). But it is very strict in case of project structure (as I have experienced) and only creates generic projects (which you convert to specific one using Project Facets). So if its major takeaway is dependency resolution then what's the point?

Comment: I think the point is that it just works the vast majority of the time, everyone knows it and all the tools work with it. I assume you came across archetypes which allow you to define your own project structure? I admit Maven is very strict and at first I found that a problem (I used to build with Ant) but now I see it as one of the plus points.

Answer (score 0):

For Enterprise Application Maven project structure is best. It is easy, widely used and independent with IDE.